# Run autopep8 on all python files except migrations doable?

Tags: django, pep8, autopep8

Am wondering is there a way to run autopep8 command on all python files exept the migrations? To fix all pep8 errors.

Instead of doing the command

```
autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive <filename>
```

Comment: Why the double-aggression?

Comment: Ah, just answered my own question. This increases the aggressiveness level: https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8#more-advanced-usage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can let `find` first look for files and then use `autopep8` on these:

```
find -type f -name '*.py' ! -path '*/migrations/*' -exec autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive '{}' \;
```

Here `find` thus looks for files that match the `*.py` glob pattern, but do *not* satisfy the `*/migrations/*` pattern for its path.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a script to automate this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Running autopep..."
find -type f -name '*.py' ! -path '*/migrations/*' -exec autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive '{}' \;

echo "Running pycodestyle..."
find -type f -name '*.py' ! -path '*/migrations/*' -exec pycodestyle --first '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `autopep8.exe --exclude='*/migrations/*' --in-place --recursive .` to run autopep8 on all files in current directory exclude migrations.